# Setting up Webstorm Jade

Tags: node.js, pug, webstorm

I m giving this error.but ide have jade plugin.

```
 An exception occurred while executing watcher 'Jade'. Watcher has been disabled Fixit.: Invalid executable
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have jade installed (you should normally run 'npm install jade -g' to do this)? If yes, please provide a full path to jade executable in a Program field of your file watcher (on Windows it would be smth like 'C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Roaming\npm\jade.cmd')

Comment: OK I had solved.I installed like dependices  jade but I forget globally.its work now